# How to add viewport meta tag to html snippet

Tags: html, atom-editor

In atom, when typing "html" and clicking on tab, I get this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, I would like to know if there is a special configuration in atom to get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    **<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">**
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I assume `html` is a default snippet, which is better not to overwrite. Try making a custom snippet instead which you can give your own name, see: https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/

Comment: Really interesting. Thank you!